# Актуально изучать jQuery версии 1.3 (по книге)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, книги

Есть книга по jQuery версии 1.3 стоитли начать изучать с нее или лучше купить 2.0

Comment: а что вас заставляет выбирать? Почему просто не купить ту, что новее?

Comment: 1.3 - очень старая версия. Актуальнее изучать по документации.

Comment: Вот и у кого такое странное желание плюсовать оффтоповые вопросы? Второй вопрос подряд...

Comment: Книга с версией 1.3 в наличии .... новая книга - это финансовые затраты от 1к до 2к рублей.

Comment: @AutoFLINSTON зато [документация](https://api.jquery.com) совершенно бесплатна.

Comment: @AutoFLINSTON 1-2 тысячи - не такие уж большие деньги. Впрочем, это, конечно, относительно. Но в любом случае к вашим услугам документация, у которой есть два неоспоримых преимущества - она бесплатна и не устаревает так как регулярно обновляется. В случае с jQuery - почему бы и нет. Это же не книга по паттернм проектирования или рефакторингу, тут в большинстве случаев достаточно документации

Comment: @AutoFLINSTON, если Вы новичок и боитесь документации, то не изучайте jQuery. Изучайте сам javascript.

Comment: @MakarovAV я бы так сказал: перед изучением jQuery стоит хорошо изучить JS. А перед этим - основы программирования, английский язык и прочее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Актуально изучать jQuery версии 1.3 (по книге)?

Однозначно неактуально. Там были большие изменения с тех пор.

Поищи что-нибудь про 1.9+.

> Книга с версией 1.3 в наличии .... новая книга - это финансовые затраты от 1к до 2к рублей.

Уверен, что можно найти онлайн-уроки и/или использовать документацию.

Да и вообще, jQuery - не та вещь, по которой имеет смысл покупать книгу. Ещё можно было бы купить, если ты уверен, что это очень хорошая книга, в которой рассказывается что-то принципиально важное, но не похоже, чтобы это был твой случай.